# Avoid Escape character in responses in WSO2 ESB API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a problem returning payload in an API in WSO2 ESB. That problems is I get:

```
http:\/\/ip:port\/test\/
```

instead of

```
http://ip:port/test/
```

in a response.

Is there any property to avoid this problem?

Comment: could you paste the ESB configuration here?

Comment: What configuration you mean exactly? Axis2 configurations? Listener?

Comment: no ESB configuration. since you are creating an API here, you can get it by viewing API in source view.

Comment: You can see in this link http://pastebin.com/4sNmhF4i